# Eclipse modify default Main method in New Class Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

When you click on `New -> Class` and you fill in the `New Class Dialog`, you can check the box `"public static void main(String[] args)"` under "Which method stubs would you like to create?"

It automatically creates the `Main method` in the new class.

I know you can modify Templates in Eclipse, so I created a new template (mymain) which will be transformed into my modified main-Method (additional code)

Can I change Eclipses behaviour to insert my custom Main when this checkbox is checked or can I modify the Template it uses for this checkbox somewhere, so whenever I check it the new Class will have my custom Main in it and not the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you  can change that, because its only creating method stubs. But you can type 'main' in any class and hit Crtl+Space -> Enter to create your predefined main method template (Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates).

Answer (score 1):

You might do it from here: Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style - Code Templates